# PHP: foreach and array issue

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have this:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $data[$key] = filter($value);
}
```

`filter();` strips if any tags, and real escape them.

Now I have an array in the POST form too, so I am getting errors in `strip_tags()` and `mysql_real_escape_string`. How should I let only `$_POST["Searching"]` not get filtered by `filter();` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [is_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php):

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if (!is_array($value))
       $data[$key] = filter($value);
}
```

Comment: Yes, in foreach, but change $_POST['Searching'] with $value. I have changed the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of [`array_walk_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php).

```
array_walk_recursive($_POST,'filter');
```

and make your function `filter` take the value by reference as:

```
function filter(&$value) {
  // apply strip_tags and real escape to $value.
  $value = mysql_real_escape(strip_tags($value));
}
```

Comment: Minor syntax - shouldn't `array_walk_recursive(&$_POST,filter);` be `array_walk_recursive(&$_POST,'filter');`? Also, just as a question for my own edification - Doesn't this function try and modify the source array in-place, rather than transcribe it to a new array, like `$data` as in the question? I see from php.net that this function only returns true or false.

Comment: Also call-time pass by reference is deprecated and will raise warnings. Should just be `array_walk_recursive($_POST, 'filter');`

Answer (score 1):

First, you can use `array_map()` to speed this up, and all you need do is allow the function to identify arrays and call itself recursively.

```
function filter( $inVar ){
  if( is_array( $inVar ) )
    return array_map( 'filter' , $inVar );
  return mysql_real_escape( strip_tags( $inVar ) );
}
```

Then call it like so:

```
$data = array_map( 'filter' , $_POST );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    if(!is_array($_POST[$key])){
        $data[$key] = filter($value);
    }else{
        $data[$key] = $value;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: This solution is incomplete - it does nothing if it hits an array. Whilst it prevents a problem with `filter()` throwing an error when it tries to handle an array, it would also mean that the array would lose data (in that any sub-arrays would be discarded).